# Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException in base_facebook.php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK V3.2.3 and have built a web based app which simply gets users albums and pics and displays them on our site after the user authorises themselves.

I have tested the site functionality on different machines on different browsers/networks and everything works as expected from our side. We can authorise as the developers set on the account as well as the test user and authorise and see the pics/albums, problem free.

I submitted the app for review and it was denied - these are the notes returned.

```
When I click on the Facebook button, I receive the following error message, 
" Fatal error:     Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in
/home/websitename/public_html/sitedir/src/base_facebook.php
on line 1325."
```

Has anybody else had this issue? I am am completely at a loss as I can't debug this as I cannot recreate the problem.

Comment: Reading more into this - it seems people have had this error by trying to access age or country restricted data which their account is not able to see. My API calls are only to get the logged in users' images so don't see how this is relevant. Also, how am I to know what the Facebook authoriser's account restrictions are?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access something in your code that you do not have access to, or something that doesn't exist.

You should always wrap your Facebook API code in try...catch statements to catch any issues and fail gracefully.

```
try {
    // some Facebook API call
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // an error occurred
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```